# How to handle slow response of ajax on div sharing by multiple function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am having one div.

```
<div id="test"></div>
```

Having few function.

```
fun1()
{
  $('#test').html('');
  $.ajax(function(){
     url : abc/index;
     success : function(response){
      $('#test').html(response);
     }
  });
}
fun2()
{
     $('#test').html('');
     $.ajax(function(){
     url : abc/getDetail;
     success : function(response){
      $('#test').html(response);
     }
  });
}
fun3()
{
 $('#test').html('');
  $.ajax(function(){
     url : abc/getUser;
     success : function(response){
      $('#test').html(response);
     }
  });
}
```

Function get call on different button click.

```
btn1.click(fun1())
btn2.click(fun2())
btn3.click(fun3())
```

When btn1,btn2, btn3 press immediately one after another, i can see div 'test' contain as first 'fun1' response after some time 'fun2' response and so on.

I know the reason, as my ajax response is very slow that's why it is happening.

When somebody click on btn1 and before getting response of fun1, press btn2. In this case i just want to load fun2 response. If fun2 is making delay want to show blank page.

I was thinking about killing remaining ajax request, on button press. But same time my other ajax request are also going, i don't want to kill those. 
So killing other ajax request will not work for me.
What will be other solution.

Comment: So is the problem the slow ajax request or the interactions between these different buttons which seem to all populate data into the same element?

Comment: @Mike Brant : slow ajax response.

Comment: Well you haven't even talked about that here.  Why is the response slow? Is the response too large? Is the server on the backend too slow in serving up the response (i.e. maybe code is poorly written, database access is slow, etc.).  But if you are really trying to get some thoughts on how to improve response speed, you will need to give specifics about where the time is being spent.

Comment: @Mike Brant : Server response is slow.

Comment: @HemantMalpole OK. But why?  Have you done any profiling/timing on the server side to understand where the code is spending its time? As it stands this question is too broad.  You haven't even answered basic things like what is size of the response payload.  If you have a huge response, maybe all your time is being spent in downloading the response.

Comment: @Mike Brant : I can't do any changes on server side now. I have manage on client side only.

Answer (score 1):

OK you have two problems

1: you are firing multiple requests off when you really only want the last one to go be processed

2: each event updates the screen regardless of what else has happened

I suggest you attack these two problems separately.

First, add a call back function for your response. this will allow you to check conditions (such as 'has anything else happened?') before updating the page. This gives you the chance to throw the first to responses out.

Secondly, you need to deal with the sending of the multiple requests in the first place. You could either cancel them when the second button is clicked, (but they will still be processed on the server) OR: You could add a timer and not immediately send the request.

Start the timer when you click the button and then say 200ms? later, fire the request and process the response.

If you get another click before the 200ms has elapsed, forget the first timer and start a  new one.

Alternatively you can prevent the user clicking buttons once a request has been sent by deactivating them and only reactivating once the response has been received.

eg: (bit crude with global vars I know)

```
    var btnLastPressed =0
    fun1()
    {
      btnLastPressed = 1;
      $('#test').html('');
      $.ajax(function(){
         url : abc/index;
         success : function(response) { finished(1,response);}
      });
    }

    function finished(btn, response){
       if(btnLastPressed==1){
          $('#test').html(response);
       }
    }
```

Comment: The issue is very simple. One div is shared by multiple ajax request. Ideally the last button click response should appear on div. One important thing is that not all ajax will never take same time to response. Say btn1 press. Its response comes afte 2 sec. Mean while somebody press btn2 and its response comes in 0.5 sec. Then btn2 response come on div after 1.5(i.e 2 - 0.5) sec btn1 response come on div.

Comment: yes, the only complexity would be if the 3rd response depended on the first two being processed. ie your ajax request does ++1 or something stateful

Comment: No response is dependent.

Comment: my solution should be fine then

Comment: You say check whether anything change in div in response. I am not getting this point

Comment: I mean add a function call instead of just updating the content. in that function you can check a global variable or something. Can you post full code?